# try catch логирование

Tags: php

Есть, допустим, ошибка при подключении к базе MsSQL. `try` ловит исключения.

Но фишка в том, что браузер первый выдаёт ошибку нежели мой `catch` запишет ошибку в логи.

Как сделать, чтоб `try` стоял выше системной ошибки?

```
$conn=getDentrix(); 
$tsq2 = "exec dbo.SetLog @svc='".$svc."', @log='".$text."'"; 
try {
    $stmt3 = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsq2);
} catch (Exception $e) { 
    file_put_contents($log_name, $e->getMessage())
}
```

Comment: Для более правильных отловов, используйте функцию [set_error_handler](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.set-error-handler.php).

Comment: Первым всегда падает скрипт, а браузер лишь выводит соответствующий ответ сервера. Если не пишется лог, можно предположить что скрипт падает до указанного вами участка кода.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

очевидно, что бы ловить ошибку, надо обернуть тот код, который, как подразумевается, будет ломаться в try

```
try{
   $conn=getDentrix(); 
   $tsq2 = "exec dbo.SetLog @svc='".$svc."', @log='".$text."'";
   $stmt3 = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsq2);
   if (!$stmt3) {
      throw new \Exception('something is wrong with connection');
   }
} catch (Exception $e) { 
   file_put_contents($log_name, $e->getMessage()
)
```

Comment: как сделать обёртку правильно